# How to view php logs information with php docker container?

Tags: php, docker, containers

I have a php-fpm docker container .  Php-fpm is run inside container, can i get php-fpm's log on host machine?  If i can,  how to do?

Answer (score 5):

The common approach is that applications inside a container don't log to a *file*, but output logs on `stdout` / `stderr`. Anything that's printed to `stdout` / `stderr` by the container's main process is collected by the built-in logging facilities of docker, and can be viewed using `docker logs <container-name>`.

By default, the logs are stored per-container using the `json-file` logging driver, and will be deleted when the container itself is deleted, but there are other logging drivers available (see [Configure logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/)) that allow you to send those logs to (e.g.) `syslog`, `journald`, `gelf`.

Also see

- [View a container's logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/view_container_logs/)
- [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Comment: If you send PHP logs (as in application logs) to stdout, they will be sent inside the HTTP response. Perhaps there's a way to send their stderr to php-fpm stderr, or similar.

Comment: @giorgiosironi here's how the official php-fpm image handles it; https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/f795769559d9ce740e57ebd32f60f8a4569ee5b6/7.2/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile#L181-L186

Comment: Thanks, but ran into https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1076 hence I abandoned the stderr approach because JSON logs get mangled or corrupted by newlines and other comments introduced by `php-fpm`.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for Docker containers is to log to `stdout`/`stderr`. However this doesn't work well for some PHP runtimes, for example `php-fpm`, because of how logs get mangled in [length](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1076) and [format](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/207).

Therefore, I switched my approach to write logs on a volume and using a [sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container) to get it into `stderr` and hence into Docker's log collection and/or your orchestrator.

Sample `docker-compose.yml` section:

```
cli:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - logs:/srv/annotations/var/logs
logger:
    image: busybox:1.27.2
    volumes:
        - logs:/logs
    # be careful, this will only tail alredy existing files
    command: tail -f /logs/all.json
    depends_on:
        - cli
```